# passenger error on production in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

This is the error I'm getting when I disable *rewrite mode* from virtual host file:

> The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application Because you are running this web application in staging or production mode, the details of the error have been omitted from this web page for security reasons.

If I do not disable rewrite mode then it gives 500 internal page error from outside my project directory.

Configuration file (*etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/*):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin support@parking.com
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@parking/gems/passenger-5.0.21
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@parking/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>

  ServerName parking.com
  ServerAlias www.parking.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parking.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://parking.com$1 [R=301,L]

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/javascript text/html text/plain text/xml text/css

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/parking-httpd-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/parking-httpd-access.log combined

  PassengerBaseURI /
  PassengerMinInstances 1
  RailsEnv production
  SetEnv RAILS_ENV "production"


  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/parking.com/public
  <Directory /var/www/sites/parking.com/public >
   # Options  +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I check my log file I found:

> [Sat Nov 21 02:43:55.498467 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 15994:tid 140692189869824] [client 127.0.0.1:46139] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/sites/parking.com/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: It looks like a generic Apache error message, not a Passenger specific one. Can you try adding `PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on` to see if Passenger is even running for this application? Also I assume you meant this is all in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/parking.conf` not, `etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/` (notice the typo).